# C++ Program Returning Numbers Instead of Char

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble figuring out why the below program is returning numbers when executed instead of 5 rows and 10 columns of pound symbols. It seems it's returning a memory address, but I'm not sure. Basically its spitting out "52428" instead of the pound symbol but in the correct pattern of 5 by 10.
Essentially I see this:

```
52428524285242852428524285242852428524285242852428
52428524285242852428524285242852428524285242852428
52428524285242852428524285242852428524285242852428
52428524285242852428524285242852428524285242852428
52428524285242852428524285242852428524285242852428
```

Code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Constants for Total Rows and Total Columns
static const unsigned short TOT_ROWS = 5, TOT_COLUMNS = 10;

//Function Prototypes
unsigned short convertChar(char);
bool isActive(unsigned short);
void initTheater(char[]);
void getTheater(char[]);
void updateheater(char[], unsigned short, unsigned short);
void storeTheater(char[]);

int main()
{
    //Variable and Array Decs
    char theater[TOT_ROWS][TOT_COLUMNS];
    double price[TOT_ROWS];
    char selection;

    //Get price input per row
    for (unsigned short rowNum = 0; rowNum < TOT_ROWS; rowNum++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the price for row " << rowNum+1 << ":";
        cin >> price[rowNum];
    }

    //Initialize Theater
    initTheater(*theater);

    //Loop to wait for one of the exit commands
    do
    {
        getTheater(*theater);
        cout << "Enter a selection: ";
        cin >> selection;
    } while (isActive(selection));
    return 0;
}

//Initalize theater by placing '#' in each array element
void initTheater(char theater[])
{
    for (unsigned short rows = 0; rows < TOT_ROWS; rows++)
    {
        for (unsigned short cols = 0; cols < TOT_COLUMNS; cols++)
        {
            theater[rows][&cols] = '#';
        }
    }
}

//Display current state of theater
void getTheater(char *theater)
{
    for (unsigned short viewRows = 0; viewRows < TOT_ROWS; viewRows++)
    {
        for (unsigned short viewCols = 0; viewCols < TOT_COLUMNS; viewCols++)
        {
            cout << theater[viewRows][&viewCols];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

//Update the Theater by placing a '*' or '#' in the specific row and seat.
void updateTheater(char *theater[], unsigned short row, unsigned short column)
{
    //Expand to determine current state of array element and flip to the alternate
    theater[row][column] = '*';
}

//Check if user has typed exit command and exit if yes
bool isActive(unsigned short selection)
{
    if (selection == '9' || selection == 'q' || selection == 'Q')
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What do you think this does: `cout << theater[viewRows][&viewCols];`? Also, how is `getTheater` supposed to know that `theater` is a two dimensional array?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Ehm.. It is not! For something like `char a[4][3]`, `a[b][c]` is actually `*(a + b*3 + c)`.

Comment: Thought just passing in the theater array would make it aware of it's structure. Regarding this: cout << theater[viewRows][&viewCols], I would expect it to take each for loop and modify the element it's access in the array on each pass. To me this reads as "read what is stored in theater[0][0] and show it, then iterate and read whats in theater[0][1] show that, iterate again and show what's in theater[0][2], etc.

Comment: @AndrewM. I think you're missing that `&viewCols` means the *address* of `viewCols`, and the address of `viewCols` will be the same regardless of its value. I'm kind of wondering what you saw that made you think this `[&` makes any sense.

Comment: That was the only way it would compile, so I just assumed I had to use it.

Comment: @David Schwartz That certainly makes sense regarding the &viewCols always returning the same value since it's referencing the mem. address. Definitely get what you're saying there. It's just VisualStudio kept spitting back at me that it didn't like it not being passed as a reference variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays just don't work at all like you seem to be expecting them to work. There's not much to say other than that you need to learn how arrays work in C++ and use them appropriately. (Or use vectors or something like that.)

In particular, the `getTheater` and `initTheater` function have no idea how the array is laid out in memory. So they can't find the elements just using `[]`'s.

In `getTheater`, you have this:

```
        cout << theater[viewRows][&viewCols];
```

In C and C++, `a[b][c]` is equivalent to `*(*(a+b)+c)`. So the above is equivalent to:

```
cout << *(*(theater + viewRows) + &viewCols);
```

Rearranging:

```
cout << * (&viewCols + *(theater+viewRows));
```

This is the same as:

```
char j = theater[viewRows];
cout << * (&viewCols + j);
```

So you're looking at what's in memory a bit past `viewCols`, looking at the wrong element of the array to decide just how far past `viewCols` to look.

Comment: Kind of got you. I'm coming from PHP and the way I did this is basically exactly the way things are done there. C/C++'s handling of this seems rather convoluted.

Comment: @AndrewM. Just don't use C-style arrays. Use vectors or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I just referenced the book I'm learning from and realized that they're explicitly declaring the second dimension of the array in the function declarations as such:

```
//Constants for Total Rows and Total Columns
static const unsigned short TOT_ROWS = 5, TOT_COLUMNS = 10;

//Function Prototypes
unsigned short convertChar(char);
bool isActive(unsigned short);
void initTheater(char[][TOT_COLUMNS]);
void getTheater(char[][TOT_COLUMNS]);
void updateTheater(char[][TOT_COLUMNS], unsigned short, unsigned short);
void storeTheater(char[][TOT_COLUMNS]);
```

That works, so for now, I'll go with that. That's for the help though everybody. Definitely gives me some other stuff to look at for the future.

Comment: This way, the functions *do* know the memory layout of the array because you've explicitly told them.